# JavaScript animation hide element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, transition

In the website that I am building, I have a `div` inside another `div`. When a header is clicked, the inner `div` should dissapear/reappear. But it's quite ugly to just change the opacity and height, so I want to add some animation so that the inner `div` does not just suddenly appear but "creates" the needed space in the outer `div` (with animation) and at the same time is reappearing (with animation). How can I achive that?

```js
$("#d1H").click(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("d2");
  if(element.style.opacity == "0") {
    element.style.opacity = "1";
    element.style.height = "auto";
  }
  else{
    element.style.opacity = "0";
    element.style.height = "0";
  }
});
```

```css
#d1{
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
#d2{
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 1rem;
}
#placeholder{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="d1">
  <h1 id="d1H">This is the outer div.</h1>
  <div id="d2">
    <h1">This is the inner div.</h1>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery has a whole slew of operations to animate showing and hiding elements, and I see you have jQuery loaded in your code. You could try toggle, or slide toggle, or fadeToggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can use [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)/.fadeOut() or [.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/).

```
    $("#d1H").click(function() {
          $("#d2").fadeToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property transition, which determines the amount of time it takes to change a CSS property. Just as a simple example to make everything transition, add this to your CSS:

```
* {
transition: 1s;
}
```

You can also do this with specific properties. Some examples are given [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)